# getFieldsAnnotatedWith annotation containing

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

**Annotation**

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Searchable {
    SearchType[] types() default { SearchType.ALL };
}
```

**Reflections in some method**

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName);
reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(); // Here's the problem
```

I would like to return all fields annotated with `Searchable` **containing at least `SearchType.ALL`**. I have tried defining a `new Searchable() { ... }` to pass with this method. Though this would result in only fields with an exact match. E.g. ONLY containing `SearchType.ALL`. This way:

```
new Searchable() {
        @Override public SearchType[] types() { return { SearchType.ALL }; }
        @Override public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() { return Searchable.class; }
        }
```

I would like fields with `@Searchable(types = { SearchType.ALL, SearchType.TEXT })` to be a hit too, since it contains `SearchType.ALL`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the Reflections API, but you can simply get all the fields annotated with the Searchable annotation, and then check if their Searchable annotation's types contains SearchType.ALL:

```
Set<Field> fields = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(Searchable.class);
Set<Field> wanted = new HashSet<Field>();
for (Field field : fields) {
    Searchable annotation = field.getAnnotation(Searchable.class);
    if (Arrays.asList(annotation.types).contains(SearchType.ALL)) {
        wanted.add(field);
    }
}
```